# Windows 10 - apple touchpad driver incomplete or damaged

Tags: mac, windows-10, drivers, touchpad, boot-camp

A few days ago my macbookpro touchpad stopped working with **windows 10**.

**My attempts to fix the issue:**

a) Looking at the device manager, I can see that the touchpad drivers (there are 2 of them for some reasons) are indeed complaining. Upgrading or 'Removing + scanning for new H/W' invariably produce the same result.

> Windows found driver software for your device but encountered an error while attempting to install it.
>   [...]
>   Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)

b) I also tried to delete the touchpad drivers via the `Programs and Features`.

> Windows Driver Package - Apple Inc. Apple Trackpad (07/13/2009 3.0.0.1)

and it fails because it cannot find the .inf file in charge if uninstalling the driver. Looking at it closely the path between what the device driver installation wizard is telling you and what's on the system is indeed slightly different.

`The Device Driver Installation Wizard says :
ERROR: File 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\aapltctp64.inf_amd64_neutral_99bcf785d5d9575a\aapltctp64.inf' not found`

It seems that I don't have a **_neutral** variant of the path. In other words the closest path I have to this is `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\aapltctp64.inf_amd64_99bcf785d5d9575a\aapltctp64.inf`

**What I changed recently**

The big changes that I had done this week was to install the latest windows 10 big update (dated Novembre 2015) which got postponed until now as it continuously failed until I forced a re-download (but that's beside the point).

The second big change was to update iTunes to latest version along with my iPhone to the latest iOS 9.2 (I believe this guy also tend to update drivers.. but I might be wrong)

Oh and last but not least, I am stuck with bootcamp 3.1 as it refuses to install the latest 3.2 as I am using a fairly old MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010). So unfortunately, I cannot install the latest drivers :(

---

*Edit 15/01/2016 :*

I didn't realize I could get specific driver events from event viewer. This is what I get :

**Event Id=43, Source=Kernel-PnP**

```
Device USB\VID_05AC&PID_0236&MI_01\7&34195f1f&0&0001 could not be migrated.
Last Device Instance Id: USB\VID_24EA&PID_0197\6&2B3428FF&0&3
Class Guid: {745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}
Location Path: 
Migration Rank: 0xF000FFFFE000F122
Present: false
Status: 0xC0000719
```

**Event Id=20003, Source=UserPnP**

```
Driver Management has concluded the process to add Service applemtp for Device Instance ID USB\VID_05AC&PID_0236&MI_01\7&34195F1F&0&0001 with the following status: 0.
```

**Event Id=20001, Source=UserPnP**

```
Driver Management concluded the process to install driver applemtp64.inf_amd64_54543ed2cd13e906\applemtp64.inf for Device Instance ID USB\VID_05AC&PID_0236&MI_01\7&34195F1F&0&0001 with the following status: 0x0.
```

So, it looks like windows is trying to "migrate" these drivers but is failing in the attempt because it cannot find them ?

Any clues on what I can try next ? Who do I need to contact ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up asking on microsoft answers forum and a support engineer gave me the [perfect answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/touchpad-not-working-running-windows-10-on-a-mac/ebee230d-bc10-4603-87e9-5048116eaf14?tm=1452860468225).

Her answer was as follow :

> The issue could be because of incompatible or corrupted drivers on the computer. Please follow the below steps to resolve the issue :
>
> - Open the Device Manager.
> - Tab once, then go down with the arrow keys to the list of unknown devices. It should say Touchpad on atleast one item.
> - Open up the properties for the Touchpad device, and try to install a driver from local disk **(do not search online, that won’t help)**.
> - Choose **USB input device** as the driver, **do not use the apple driver just yet**.  After the installation is finished, your touchpad will
>     work.
> - After installing the USB driver you can perform the same steps, but pick the Apple driver. After the installation is complete, your
>     touchpad will work as expected.

And it does !

Comment: All I had to do was disable and re enable the driver. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem after applying the November update on a 32bit windows 10 installed on a late 2011 MacBookPro. I was able to get rid of the November update by using the uninstall option for the update in "Programs and Features". What I found is that after the update, the Apple Touchpad driver version was something like 3.0.2, while the previous driver version was 4.0.0.1. It appears that the update somehow installs an older, incompatible version of the Touchpad driver.

Comment: `It appears that the update somehow installs an older, incompatible version of the Touchpad driver` Do you think so ? That would be so strange. Where would it get it from ?

Also, can someone explain why the driver changed path from `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\aapltctp64.inf_amd64_neutral_99bcf785d5d9575a\aapltctp64.inf` to `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\aapltctp64.inf_amd64_99bcf785d5d9575a\aapltctp64.inf`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions you guys suggested, but the problem happened again when I restarted my Macbook Pro (2015).

What worked for me was to uninstall all Apple multi-touch, keyboard and trackpad drivers in Control Panel > Programs and Features which had a different build version than that of the Apple SPI trackpad driver in Device Manager.

However, sometime it doesn't work. I finally solved the problem by reinstalling the OS and updating the boot camp driver.